# Increase only the line of an arrow using ax.quiver from matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some geodetic stations and the values of their displacements over two year.
I'm using `ax.quiver`to get the arrows of displacements on my figure.

The problem is that the displacements are much smaller than the position of the stations and when I use `scale=0.0001` (or something like this), all the arrow increase and I need that only the length increase, not their whole body.

My code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
ax.scatter(eee_SB_um,nnn_SB_um,edgecolors='none',marker='o', color='r')

plt.axis('equal')

ax.quiver(eee_SB_um, nnn_SB_um, DSB_1_E, DSB_1_N,
          angles='xy',scale_units='xy', scale = 0.0001)
```

My figure:
[image: Plot of displacements]

Comment: Someone can help me??

Comment: See [ask] and [mcve] for how to produce a question that people can you help you with.

Comment: Give a handful of sample values for all of your variables which recreate your problem.